# Cannot enter dot in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

In my grid view i have link type column. as we cannot edit cell of such type i am displaying a text box if user select cell for editing. but my text box is unable read dot character. I checked "key pressed"  and "text changed" events but events are not triggered for dot as a input.

EDIT:
I can enter any character or symbol except dot.. ;(

I am displaying textbox on cell click event of gridview

```
if (DataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType().Name == "DataGridViewLinkColumn")
{
txt_Data.Location    =   DataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location;

txt_Data.Size        =   DataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Size;

txt_Data.Visible     =   true;
txt_Data.Focus();
}
```

And assigning a value to cell as

```
private void txt_Data_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid.CurrentCell.Value = txt_Data.Text;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this. Are you attaching to the key events on the textbox or the grid?

Comment: So to be clear the txt_Data_TextChanged event isn't firing? Or is it just that the current cell doesn't get the dot?

Comment: no i cant enter dot in textbox.. if i press dot nothing happn..:(

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I just can't help saying "dot's a real problem"...  

:)

Comment: Did you figure out what was happening? I have a similar problem, although I have more characters that cannot be entered . ! " $ % & ( ' #. I am new to .net c# and have inherited this code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few days ago and it was driving me nuts.. Finally figured it out so I've come back here to enlighten :) The problem is the [EditingControlWantsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol.editingcontrolwantsinputkey.aspx) method for your editing control.. Make sure it returns true for all characters (or at least the characters you want to support).. Done! :D