# Can't use Decimal values

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I've created a TextBox in which currency values have to be entered but now I am not able to enter .(dot) in the textbox for decimal values. I have written the code in Text_changed event.
The code

```
 int cursorLocation = ((TextBox)(sender)).SelectionStart;

            string inputval = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
            inputval = inputval.Replace("*", "");
            inputval = inputval.Replace("#", "");
            inputval = inputval.Replace(",", "");
            inputval = inputval.Replace(" ", "");
            inputval = inputval.Replace("-", "");
            Decimal inputval1 = Convert.ToDecimal(inputval);

            ((TextBox)sender).Text = inputval1.ToString("###,###");
            cursorLocation = ((TextBox)(sender)).Text.Length;

            //((TextBox)sender).Text = inputval;
            ((TextBox)(sender)).SelectionStart = cursorLocation;
```

Comment: Consider the following post please:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544054/cannot-enter-dot-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this under textchanged event and this worked,

```
 try
        {
            string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
             long ul;
             if (long.TryParse(value, out ul))
             {
                 TextBox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
                 TextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#}", ul);
                 TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
                 TextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
                 this.TextBox.MaxLength = 10;
             }
        }
        catch { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
((TextBox)sender).Text = inputval1.ToString("###,###");
```

Whenever you enter new character, the whole textbox.text gets overwritten with the new text in the format ###,###

Comment: @yogesh see here, it's well explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039338/textbox-with-decimal-input-improvement and play around a bit. :)